# Field is not a leaf field

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting an error " Field signupdate is not a leaf field" for following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM [adknowledge_data.ADKBatch_Combined_c]
WHERE ABS(HASH(MD5email) % 3 ) = 0
GROUP EACH BY MD5email, signupdate
HAVING cnt > 1
```

For following table schema:

> MD5email: string
>
> IP: string
>
> signupdate: timestamp

Answer (score 5):

That's not a nice error message, but at least there's an easy solution to the underlying problem: Include 'signupdate' on the SELECT expression.

See:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM [fh-bigquery:bigdataspain.aggr_transactions_to] 
GROUP BY time

Error: Field time [...] is not a leaf field.
```

Vs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c, time
FROM [fh-bigquery:bigdataspain.aggr_transactions_to] 
GROUP BY time

(works!)
```